# WebSocket is not working with https request and its working fine with http using PHP ratchet Library

Tags: php, apache, websocket, ratchet

I don't know much about WebSocket, and I have implemented WebSocket using the ratchet PHP library, but it is working HTTP request, but not working with HTTPS request on the some code on google APP engine. my website code hosted on google APP engine and my socket code is hosted on google compute engine.

Is there confirmation on Apache server? If Yes then Can you please suggest me?

Answer (score 0):

For SSL Request please make changes in "/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default-le-ssl.conf" file at end.

> ProxyPass /wss2/ ws://domainname.com:8080/

Also to make changes in your send request file WebSocket URL:

> socket = new
>   WebSocket("wss://domainname.com/wss2/:8080/?parameter=parameterValue");

I have made mistakes in passing port to the wrong way when I call WebSocket using Angular